# SuiteCRM parse error when trying to add a js file to a view

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am just trying to add jquery and jquery.maskedinput to a custom edit view for Accounts module. I saw a post explaining this: https://www.suitecrm.co.uk/forum/developer-help/9598-one-of-the-two-required-fields-to-be-filled-in-accounts-module?start=15

My code:

```
<?php

if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('modules/Accounts/views/view.edit.php');

class CustomAccountsViewEdit extends AccountsViewEdit {

public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
     }


function display(){

 //call parent display method
 #       parent::display();


$js = <<<JS

            <script src="/admin/custom/include/javascript/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            <script src="/admin/custom/include/javascript/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    JS;
        parent::display();
        echo $js;

    }

}
```

The error I am getting:

> [error] 1846#0: *244 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse
>   error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/custom/modules/Accounts/views/view.edit.php on
>   line 31" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x,
>   server: , request: "GET
>   /index.php?module=Accounts&action=EditView&return_module=Accounts&return_action=DetailView
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "x.x.x.x",
>   referrer: "http://x.x.x.x/index.php?action=ajaxui"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to php docs, the heredoc identifier should not be indented. See how there's no space before `JS;`?

```
$js = <<<JS

            <script src="/admin/custom/include/javascript/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
            <script src="/admin/custom/include/javascript/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript">
JS;
        parent::display();
        echo $js;

    }
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank You